# php script can be stopped?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to make a paypal IPN system, this is a system of paypal to automatically check money transfers. They provide a basic system script to do it.

The system is easy, you get $_POST[] on your script, and then open a socket versus paypal, and they response to you valid or invalid word in the socket.

My problem is that opening the socket, 50% of times i'm getting connection lost. When the script connect, I don't have any problem. So I changed it to 20 trys, instead 1:

```
<?

//...

mail("mi@mail.com", "subject", "executing", "some headers"); //mailme when this is execute

$try = 20;
do{
  $fp = @fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 15);
  $try--;
}while($try>0 && !$fp);

if (!$fp) { // HTTP ERROR

mail("mi@mail.com", "subject", "error_message_not_connecting", "some headers");

} else {

mail("mi@mail.com", "subject", "connected_reading_socket", "some headers");

//fputs(..); and the loop reading working.

}

?>
```

In my test, it works now 100% of severals trys. But in real transfers, it doesn't work 20-30% of times. I'm getting the 1st mail, but never the second one in that fails.

I'm thinking.. If paypal only open the connection to my server 1 second, can the php script stop after some trys, and stop going on? or any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: You can add a delay counter act as a timer that increases over failure and `sleep` but that amount of time inside your `while` loop. This way you'll get more chances of getting a successful connection in less tries

Comment: use curl -- php function may be better to handling the connection. so, you can check the error message which get from the connection.

Comment: @pankar Assuming you have max execution time increased, too. Otherwise it will just increase your chances that PHP cuts you off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. A php can be stopped when a users close the conection to the server (usually by click stop button on browser, or in this case a socket closed by paypal).

There are 3 ways to stop a script.

1-by finish the script
2-by user closeing the conection to the server
3-by timeout

I used the function ignore_user_abort(true), and I dont have more problems.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Answer (score 1):

Sending the mail can fail too, especially if you have network issues. You should log the failure conditions, for both mail() as well as your fsockopen, so you can revisit them afterwards.

Also, your fsockopen can get stuck. You have a 15 second timeout and you try 20 times, so your script will work for 20*15=300 seconds = 5 minutes, which is probably longer than your PHP script timeout -> PHP would abort your script mid-process, right? Max execution time is only 30 seconds by default in PHP.

Comment: mail is not failing. Anyway, after send the email, i have some inserts on my db, and I dont have any when it fails.

Comment: execution time is 12 hours, that is what the host says. When I execute 20 trys manually, connecting or not, i dont have problems. Also i execute some script with more time with no problems :(

Comment: @user1475451 so that tells you either that a) script was stopped mid-process, b) connection failed and mail sending failed, possibly with the same root cause. Based on the code, either of them could be the reason, although you are right that if the first call to mail works, I would investigate a). Proper logging would help the diagnostics. I assume you already checked the error logs of the server.

Comment: one thing you could test is to use [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to see if your script was aborted mid-process.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP script can be stopped with `exit;`.
You can pause the php script proccessing with `sleep(nr_sec)`.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get similar problems. Strange behavior when usin sockets. 
Better use CURL instead, it's more stable.

http://leepeng.blogspot.com/2006/04/standard-paypal-php-integration.html